# Can I create a crash dump for my launch daemon on a macOS when it crashes?

Tags: macos, daemon, sigabrt, crash-dumps

I've written a launch daemon for macOS. (It's written in C++.)

The daemon works in most cases, except that once in a while I see that it receives the SIGABRT signal from the own process. (I can see it in a log.)

Because this happens at some random moments, I can't attach a debugger to it.

I'm new to development for macOS. Most of my experience comes from Windows. Thus, I'm wondering if it's possible to generate a crash dump when my daemon receives SIGABRT? And if so, would Xcode allow me to analyze that crash dump file later?

PS. In general how do you guys do it on a macOS?

Comment: You might already get crash reports in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` (if the daemon is running in the system domain) or in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` (if it's running in the user domain). Be sure to keep your debug symbols around, then use a tool like [MacSymbolicator](https://github.com/inket/MacSymbolicator) to get useful stack traces from the crash log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create it yourself, it will be created by the OS for you. You just need to know where to find it and how to read it. Check [this blog post](https://dennisbabkin.com/blog/?t=macos-programming-xcode-build-schemes-diagnose-memory-corruption-and-crashes#dbg_w_crash_log) for details.